# Copying and pasting all rows with a given value in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to create a master worksheet in a Excel database that will allow me to input a reference number into a cell, then run a macro to list all instances of the reference number.

For instance, if I input reference number 0001 in cell E8, I can click a command button that will find all instances that 0001 occurs in a neighboring worksheet, then copy and paste all rows relating in a range.

This is the code I have at the moment, however, there is no copy and pasting. It will clear the contents of B35:B100 and select the cell E8 at the end, but nothing appears to happen in between.

Any ideas why copy and pasting isn't working?

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReturnActions()

Dim itemnumber As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheet1.Range("B35:N100").ClearContents

itemnumber = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value 'master worksheet
finalrow = Sheet3.Range("G10").End(xlUp).Row 'database of information

For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = itemnumber Then
        Sheet3.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 12)).Copy 'database worksheet
        Sheet1.Range("B50").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'master worksheet
        End If
Next i

Range("E8").Select 'master wowrksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Qualify all the ranges with the sheet.  You do this, for example, with `Sheet3.Range()`, but you also need to do it when you use `Cells()`, so your `Copy` line becomes `Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(i, 2), Sheet3.Cells(i, 12)).Copy 'database worksheet` and the `If` line should be `If sheet3.Cells(i,1) = itemnumber Then` (assuming of course it's going to be on `Sheet3`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found out where I've gone wrong. I forgot to activate between the two sheets. The reformatted code which works is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReturnActions()

Dim itemnumber As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Sheet1.Range("B35:N100").ClearContents

itemnumber = Sheet1.Range("E8").Value
finalrow = Sheet3.Range("G10").End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Total List").Activate
For i = 2 To finalrow
    If Cells(i, 7) = itemnumber Then
        Sheet3.Range(Cells(i, 7), Cells(i, 12)).Copy
        Sheet1.Range("B50").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
Next i

Worksheets("Action Entry").Activate

Range("E8").Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to use AutoFilter and paste the "Visible" cells

```
' Assumes data starts in cell A1 on each sheet
Sheet3.range("A1").Autofilter Criteria1:= Sheet1.Range("E8").Value
Sheet3.range("A1").currentregion.select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheet1.Activate
Sheet1.Range("A1").Select
Sheet1.Paste
```